# How to generate call to base constructor with VarArgs using ILGenerator

Tags: c#, il, ilgenerator

If I decompile the Test2 constructor:

```
public class Test2 : VarArgTest
{
    public Test2() : base("foo", __arglist("one", 2))
    {

    }
}

public class VarArgTest
{
    public VarArgTest(string test, __arglist)
    {

    }
}
```

I get this IL:

```
IL_0000:  ldarg.0
IL_0001:  ldstr      "foo"
IL_0006:  ldstr      "one"
IL_000b:  ldc.i4.2
IL_000c:  call       instance vararg void VarargsTest.VarArgTest::.ctor(string,
                                                                        ...,
                                                                        string,
                                                                        int32)
```

I'm trying to generate the same IL stream using the ILGenerator but [EmitCall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator.emitcall%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) only takes a MethodInfo not a ConstructorInfo and the only [Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h8y9503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload that takes a ConstructorInfo has no support for passing in additional parameter types.

Comment: @WilliamAndrewMontgomery the code compiles just fine, Intellisense, however, doesn't seem to like it (for reasons you've mentioned probably).

Comment: @WilliamAndrewMontgomery Yes as a C# language construct it is undocumented but I wasn't suggesting using it from C#, that was just to illustrate the code that generated the IL. 
As far as I know the ILGenerator is not language specific and it supports varargs for method calls (see [EmitCall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator.emitcall%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) so the question was whether it supports varargs for base constructor calls as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, After reading this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yirutang/archive/2005/04/29/413573.aspx)

I discovered an incredibly easier method of doing this:
You can get a token for the constructor with optional arguments from your method builder. Why this is so unbelievably undocumented is a mystery. A similar version of the program in my previous answer is below that does the same thing but with just using this get methodtoken api. 
This is much easier!

```
var ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("Foo"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
var mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule(ab.GetName().Name, ab.GetName().Name + ".dll", true);
var tb = mb.DefineType("Foo", TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit | TypeAttributes.AnsiClass | TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.AutoClass | TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(VarArgTest));
var ctor = tb.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName, CallingConventions.HasThis, Type.EmptyTypes);
var il = ctor.GetILGenerator();
var token= mb.GetConstructorToken(typeof(VarArgTest).GetConstructors()[0], new[] { typeof(string), typeof(int) });
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "foo");
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "one");
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_2);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call,token.Token);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
var v = Activator.CreateInstance(tb.CreateType());
Console.WriteLine((v as VarArgTest).CountOfArgs);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this isn't possible; I suspect it's merely an oversight that `MethodInfo` was used as the input type instead of `MethodBase`, since it appears to be perfectly valid to have varargs `.ctor`s.  You could try filing a bug, but I suspect that this is a low priority scenario to support, given that varargs methods aren't CLS compliant.

Comment: I think that the fact that the documentation for `EmitCall` says that `opcode` can be `Newobj` supports this. (`Newobj` only makes sense with `ConstructorInfo`, but not with `MethodInfo`, right?)

Answer (score 2):

Sadly it appears @kvb is correct. That said, the method you want to do the hard work "GetMethodToken" does appear to take a methodbase. So if you aren't opposed to expression trees you can make your own version of the method. Here is my best guess (minus argument validation)
I haven't fully test it in every scenario, bUt you can now use func as a method to call a vararg method or a vararg ctor.
::

```
var ilgen = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ILGenerator));
var code = Expression.Parameter(typeof(OpCode));
var method = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MethodBase));
var opttypes = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Type[]));
var stackchange = Expression.Variable(typeof(int));
var tok = Expression.Variable(typeof(int));
var paramTypes= Expression.Variable(typeof(Type[]));
var expr = Expression.Lambda<Action<ILGenerator, OpCode, MethodBase, Type[]>>(Expression.Block(
new[]{stackchange,tok,paramTypes},
Expression.Assign(stackchange, Expression.Constant(0)),
Expression.Assign(tok,
    Expression.Call(ilgen,
        typeof(ILGenerator)
            .GetMethod("GetMethodToken", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance),
        method,
        opttypes,
        Expression.Constant(false)
    )
),
Expression.Call(ilgen, typeof(ILGenerator).GetMethod("EnsureCapacity", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic), Expression.Constant(7)),
Expression.Call(ilgen, typeof(ILGenerator).GetMethod("InternalEmit",BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.NonPublic), code),
Expression.IfThen(
    Expression.AndAlso(
        Expression.Not(
            Expression.Property(method, "IsConstructor")
        ),
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(
                Expression.Convert(method, typeof(MethodInfo)),
                "ReturnType"
            ),
            Expression.Constant(typeof(void))
        )
    ),
    Expression.PostIncrementAssign(stackchange)
),
Expression.Assign(paramTypes, Expression.Call(method,
    typeof(MethodInfo)
        .GetMethod("GetParameterTypes", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    )
),
Expression.IfThen(
    Expression.AndAlso(
        Expression.AndAlso(
            Expression.TypeIs(method, Type.GetType("System.Reflection.Emit.SymbolMethod")),
            Expression.Property(method, "IsStatic")
        ),
        Expression.Equal(
            code,
            Expression.Constant(OpCodes.Newobj, typeof(OpCode))
        )
    ),
    Expression.PostDecrementAssign(stackchange)
),
Expression.IfThen(Expression.NotEqual(opttypes, Expression.Constant(null)),
    Expression.SubtractAssign(stackchange, Expression.ArrayLength(opttypes))
),
Expression.Call(ilgen, typeof(ILGenerator).GetMethod("UpdateStackSize", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance), code, stackchange),
Expression.Call(ilgen, typeof(ILGenerator).GetMethod("RecordTokenFixup", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)),
Expression.Call(ilgen, typeof(ILGenerator).GetMethod("PutInteger4", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance),tok)
),
ilgen, code, method, opttypes);
var func = expr.Compile();
```

From here you can use it on your type like so:

```
public class VarArgTest
{
    public int CountOfArgs;
    public VarArgTest(string test, __arglist)
    {
        ArgIterator args = new ArgIterator(__arglist);
        CountOfArgs = args.GetRemainingCount();
    }
}
```

//then in the method to create the class

```
var ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("Foo"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
var mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule(ab.GetName().Name, ab.GetName().Name + ".dll", true);
var tb = mb.DefineType("Foo", TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit | TypeAttributes.AnsiClass | TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.AutoClass | TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(VarArgTest));
var ctor = tb.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName,CallingConventions.HasThis,Type.EmptyTypes);
var il =ctor.GetILGenerator();
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "foo");
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "one");
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_2);
func(il, OpCodes.Call, typeof(VarArgTest).GetConstructors()[0], new[] { typeof(string), typeof(int) });
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
var v=Activator.CreateInstance(tb.CreateType());
Console.WriteLine((v as VarArgTest).CountOfArgs);
```

Prints 2.